# ajax crud edit and remove works only on first row

Tags: php, ajax, crud

I'm a beginner with AJAX in combination with php. I've a crud and he only edit and remove the first row.
I think i need to add anywhere a another id but i've no idea where.

Here is my HTML

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM crud_gegevens";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {       
         echo '<tr><td><input type="text" id="mod" value="'.$row['naam'].'"></td>';         
         echo '<td><input type="text" id="ctgr" value="'.$row['adres'].'"></td>';
         echo '<td><input type="hidden" id="gegevens_id" value="'.$row['gegevens_id'].'"></td>';
         echo '<td><button type="submit" id="update">update</button></td>';
         echo '<td><button type="submit" id="delete">delete</button></td></tr>';
    }
```

my js / ajax is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        var id=$("#gegevens_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'delete.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                id:id
            },
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And my function in php is this

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$sql="DELETE FROM crud_gegevens where gegevens_id='$id'";
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "DATA deleted";
}
```

Comment: add  $(this).("#gegevens_id").val(); i think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **data-id** for get individual id for each row in ajax
and use **id="deleteBtn"** for click event in jquery

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {       
     echo '<tr><td><input type="text" id="mod" value="'.$row['naam'].'"></td>';         
     echo '<td><input type="text" id="ctgr" value="'.$row['adres'].'"></td>';
     echo '<td><button type="submit" id="update">update</button></td>';
     echo '<td><button type="submit" id="deleteBtn" data-id="'. $row['gegevens_id'] . '">delete</button></td></tr>';
}
```

there is no need extra hidden input field.

**js script**

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteBtn', function(){
var id = $(this).data('gegevens_id');
$.ajax({
    url:'delete.php',
    method:'POST',
    data:{
        id:id
    },
    success:function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
   });
});
```